# BeanCreationException of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hibernate, sqlite, maven-3

Hi and thanks for read my problem.

I am writing a simple program to admin users, cars, payments.. in a garage. thhis is a maven project and i use spring and hibernate wiht sqlite.
I am geting this excetion when i try just to exetuce a basic test of my aplication

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clienteDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory Modelo.GenericDaoHibernate.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory Modelo.GenericDaoHibernate.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:396)
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:117)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1596)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1519)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1420)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
... 52 more
```

I let you here my pom here:

```
  <groupId>abegondo.taller</groupId>
  <artifactId>taller</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>taller</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

 <!-- Versions -->
    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <junit.version>4.8.1</junit.version>
    <sqlite.version>3.7.15-M1</sqlite.version>

 <!-- Hibernate properties -->
    <hibernate.show_sql>true</hibernate.show_sql>
    <hibernate.format_sql>true</hibernate.format_sql>
    <hibernate.use_sql_comments>true</hibernate.use_sql_comments>

 <dataSource.url>jdbc:sqlite:taller</dataSource.url>
 <testDataSource.url>jdbc:sqlite:taller</testDataSource.url>           
  </properties>
<repositories>

<repository>
<id>hibernatesqlite-maven</id>
<url>https://hibernate-sqlite.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
    <id>java.net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
</repository>

</repositories>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
<!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${sqlite.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.GA</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sqlite</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- JDBC driver properties -->
            <jdbcDriver.groupId>org.xerial</jdbcDriver.groupId>
            <jdbcDriver.artifactId>sqlite</jdbcDriver.artifactId>
            <jdbcDriver.version>${sqlite.version}</jdbcDriver.version>
            <jdbcDriver.className>org.sqlite.JDBC</jdbcDriver.className>

            <!-- Data source properties -->
            <dataSource.url>jdbc:sqlite:taller</dataSource.url>
            <testDataSource.url>jdbc:sqlite:taller</testDataSource.url>                <dataSource.createTablesScript>src/main/resources/CreateTables.sql</dataSource.createTablesScript>
            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <hibernate.dialect>Modelo.SQLiteDialect</hibernate.dialect>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    </profiles>

  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${jdbcDriver.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <driver>${jdbcDriver.className}</driver>
                <username>${dataSource.user}</username>
                <password>${dataSource.password}</password>
                <srcFiles>
                    <srcFile>${dataSource.createTablesScript}</srcFile>
                </srcFiles>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- The default sql:execute creates the production db -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${dataSource.url}</url>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-test-db</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${testDataSource.url}</url>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>es.udc.protoduction.Sprodion</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    </build>

</project>
```

my hibernate-conf.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Show and print SQL on stdout -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">Modelo.SQLiteDialect</property>

    <mapping class="Modelo.Entidades.Cliente"/>
    <mapping class="Modelo.Entidades.Coche"/>
    <mapping class="Modelo.Entidades.Factura"/>
    <mapping class="Modelo.Entidades.LineaFactura"/>
    <mapping class="Modelo.Entidades.Pieza"/>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My spring configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd " >
    <context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="Modelo"/>

<bean id="jdbcDataSource3" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-     method="close" lazy-init="true">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:taller" /> 
<property name="initialSize" value="2" />
<property name="maxActive" value="20" />
<property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
<property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbcDataSource3"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate-config.xml"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

Any idea why can this exception be throwed?

Comment: try `<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate-config.xml"/>`

Comment: Can you post your actual test code. You need to have Spring specific configuration annotations added to your test -- This won't tell whether you have added them or added them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i solved this problem sorry for answer here late.
I had an annotation bad, I write the @Id in an Set field instead of the correct id of the entity